# Optimising recursive apply calls for applying different functions on the same dataset

Tags: r, apply, lapply

I am applying several functions on a different subsets of rows of a matrix. Here is some example data:

```
set.seed(1)
## The data is a simple matrix
dataset <- matrix(sample(1:25, 25), 5, 5)

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    7   18    4   19    6
#[2,]    9   22    3   25   16
#[3,]   14   12   24    8    2
#[4,]   20   11   21   23   15
#[5,]    5    1   13   10   17

## The subsets is a list contain a list of matrices where the columns represent the rows of data
subsets <- list(list(matrix(seq(1:5), ncol = 1), matrix(c(c(1:3), c(2:4), c(3:5)), ncol = 3)))
#[[1]]
#[[1]][[1]]
#     [,1]
#[1,]    1
#[2,]    2
#[3,]    3
#[4,]    4
#[5,]    5
#
#[[1]][[2]]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    2    3
#[2,]    2    3    4
#[3,]    3    4    5

## The functions to apply successively (the first one outputs a matrix, the second a single numeric)
function_list <- list(var, sd)
```

In this example the first level of the `subset` list contains only one element but can contain more.
I want to apply the first and second function consecutively to the matrix for each rows selected in subsets. For example:

```
sd(var(dataset[c(1,2,3,4,5), ]))
#[1] 35.6238
```

Or more specifically:

```
## The first function
(subset_out <- function_list[[1]](dataset[subsets[[1]][[1]][,1], ]))
#      [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]
#[1,] 36.50   3.25  40.25  11.25  -4.25
#[2,]  3.25  63.70 -40.50  40.75 -12.70
#[3,] 40.25 -40.50  91.50 -37.25 -18.00
#[4,] 11.25  40.75 -37.25  58.50  23.25
#[5,] -4.25 -12.70 -18.00  23.25  45.70

## The second function
function_list[[2]](subset_out)
#[1] 35.6238
```

My solution so far is to use `lapply` and `apply` calling the functions on the data but it seems a bit cumbersome and slow:

```
## Apply consecutively both functions to one matrix within the subsets list
lapply.to.one.subset <- function(one_subset, function_list, dataset){

    ## Apply the first function
    subset_out <- apply(one_subset, 2, function(X, fun, dataset) fun(dataset[X, ]), function_list[[1]], dataset)

    ## Apply the second function
    subset_out <- apply(subset_out, 2, function_list[[2]])

    return(subset_out)
}

## apply to the whole subset
lapply(subsets, lapply, lapply.to.one.subset, function_list, dataset)

#[[1]]
#[[1]][[1]]
#[1] 35.6238

#[[1]][[2]]
#[1] 57.47624 55.63089 31.68247
```

In my case, many more elements are present in the `subset` list as well as more functions in `function_list` with several more conditional statements in the `lapply.to.one.subset` function (removed for simplifying). This makes it fairly (really) slow for big datasets.
Any thoughts on how to get to the same results faster?

Comment: Suggestion: parallelize. This seems ideal for parallelization. Q: Does the same `subset` set of values occur multiple times? Might make sense to "pre-compute" results for all possible subsets.

Comment: Simply through `snow::parLapply`? A: I doubt it. The matrices are generally big and the subsets are effectively bootstraps of the matrices rows (which are supposed to be random).

Comment: Unrelated: in the edit queue, I came across a question that you voted on in triage. You made the wrong choice there. Please: study the help for triage really carefully, and avoid putting items into the edit queue that don't belong there. Please understand that your votes have consequences! I am specifically talking about https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/20898974. This is (almost) zero effort homework dump. Only the OP can edit it to improve it, nobody else! Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parallelize through `parallel:parLapply`, like so

```
library(parallel)
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores()-1)
clusterExport(
    cl,
    c("dataset", "subsets", "function_list", "lapply.to.one.subset")
)
```

Since you have a nested list, you will need to choose whether to parallelize the outer list

```
# parallelize outer loop - subset[1-N]
parLapply(
    cl,
    subsets,
    function(i) {
        lapply(i, function(j) lapply.to.one.subset(j, function_list, dataset))
    }
)
```

Or the inner nested list

```
# parallelize inner loop - subset[[1]][1-N]
lapply(
    subsets,
    function(i) {
        parLapply(
            cl,
            i,
            function(j) { lapply.to.one.subset(j, function_list, dataset) }
        )
    }
)
```

Shut down your parallel cluster

```
stopCluster(cl)
rm(cl)
```

Comment: Note when benchmarking make sure to use data at a scale close to that of your real data. Since initializing parallel workers takes time, with a small data set, parallel alternative can be slower

Comment: When benchmarking at the `parLapply` level (ignoring the cluster initialization) it's already six times faster on this trivial example. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check speed as it is going to be slower than a parallel solution, but the following does seem to work.

```
library(dplyr)
lapply(subsets, lapply, function(lst) apply(lst, 2, 
                           function(Y) dataset[Y, , drop = FALSE] %>%
                              function_list[[1]]() %>% 
                                   function_list[[2]]()))
```